Centos 7: Intel X540 (10Gbit Ethernet) not working. "Network unclaimed" - ixgbe loaded but not initialized
Iam currently running Centos 7 on a KVM host server and newly installed a Intel X540 10Gbit ethernet adapter.
And before you jump to conclusions:

The adapter is detected and works perfectly well on that machine when I boot a LIVE Centos 7.9 2009 or Ubuntu.

-> No hardware or Bios issue...
When I boot into the installed Centos 7 the adapter shows unter lspci
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X540 (rev 01)

but under lshw -class network shows the network as unclaimed:
 *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Controller X540
       vendor: Intel(R)
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dda00000-ddbfffff memory:ddc00000-ddc03fff memory:dfd00000-dfd7ffff

The ixgbe driver is installed In-Tree as it is on the LIVE system as well:
modinfo ixgbe
filename:       /lib/modules/3.10.0-1160.119.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe.ko.xz
version:        5.1.0-k-rh7.7
license:        GPL v2
description:    Intel(R) 10 Gigabit PCI Express Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
retpoline:      Y
rhelversion:    7.9
srcversion:     C8FAAC70303B2D7D0E691BE

[...]

depends:        mdio,ptp,dca
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.10.0-1160.119.1.el7.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         CentOS Linux kernel signing key
sig_key:        68:EA:10:3F:2C:90:A8:DC:0B:B0:44:6C:06:D1:45:61:F2:9E:11:72
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
parm:           max_vfs:Maximum number of virtual functions to allocate per physical function - default is zero and maximum value is 63 (uint)
parm:           allow_unsupported_sfp:Allow unsupported and untested SFP+ modules on 82599-based adapters (uint)
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)

The driver is loaded but does not seem to claim the card/initialize it:
dmesg | grep ixgbe
[    2.475936] ixgbe: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit PCI Express Network Driver - version 5.1.0-k-rh7.7
[    2.475938] ixgbe: Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Intel Corporation.

I compiled the latest intel driver 5.21 and loaded it via modprobe with exactly the same result: dmesg shows the driver being loaded but nothing else happens.
Driver dependencies "mdio, ptp and dca" are both present and loaded.
############ UPDATE: ################
15min after my post I found what 2 days of internet research did not produce:
[https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/kernel-fails-to-assign-memory-to-pcie-device-4175487043/][1]
For some unknown reason the kernel fails to allocate PCIe ressources to the card at startup:
[    0.647435] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.647437] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.647439] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.647440] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit pref]
[    0.904604] pci 0000:02:00.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt

Quick-Fix:
Releasing the card and rescan for it makes it startup just fine without any issues...
#echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:02\:00.0/remove
#echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan

So the question remains what is the actual solution to that as even with the latest driver this happens.
Thx for your support !
